# Python Azure GetSharedAccessSignature

Tags: python, azure

Python SDK for Azure does not has `GetSharedAccessSignature` to generate aceess signature.

How can I do it in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the source code for [Azure SDK for Python](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python) on Github especially this: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/src/azure/storage/sharedaccesssignature.py.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the above link is broken. 
I've found this documentation really helpful and slightly difficult to find:
http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-python/